# Using NPM 'pre' scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

With NPM we can use pre scripts to run as pre hooks (also there are post hooks).

I want to run 'gulp default' before running my npm script like so:

```
"scripts":{
   "prestart_dev": "gulp default",
    "start_dev": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

I run this:

```
npm run start_dev
```

the prestart_dev runs, as expected, but it doesn't kick off start_dev, it just sits there. Any idea what I can do to fix it? Seems like it should work as is.

My Gulp default task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {

    gulp.run('build_requirejs_pipe');

    gulp.watch('public/static/app/js/controllers/**/*.js', function () {
        gulp.run('build_requirejs_pipe');
    });

});
```

(it could be that my default task need to return something?)

Comment: Could you paste the code of your gulp default task?

Comment: If you run the scripts individually, does `node ./bin/www` run correctly?

Comment: Wait so what you are essentially saying is when you do `npm run start_dev`, it ends up running `prestart_dev`? I believe `npm run` should only be running the script you specify. You can chain scripts if you want i.e. `"start-dev": "npm run prestart_dev && node ./bin/www"`

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi does my default task need to return something?

Comment: I updated the question with code for my gulp default task, of course no errors are problems are thrown or detected by it.

Comment: @AlexMills as it was correctly pointed out by Peter Lyons, the 'pre' task should in fact return in order to make npm move on to the main task.

Comment: thx, it does return but it returns undefined, so I return what?

Answer (score 4):

So my hunch is that `gulp default` remains in the foreground as it watches for filesystem changes forever until explicitly stopped. Thus from npm's perspective, `prestart_dev` never completes and thus it doesn't proceed to `start_dev`.

Generally for development, most developers want to run their server process in the foreground in one terminal and any watch-based utilities also in the foreground in a separate terminal. You might consider just leaving these 2 things independent as opposed to coupling them.

Comment: Yes it is caused by the watch